# Scrapy Next page link is giving nothing

Tags: python, xpath, automation, scrapy, ui-automation

Hello I want to go to every page of this site by clicking on the next page `https://www.dehatilyrics.top/`

But the Xpath of Next page is not giving anything not even an empty dictionary.

How to get the next page links of such site?

Comment: Which one did you try? Also how do you want *to click something* in Scrapy? Do you mean Selenium?

Comment: I tried many for example take this one which chrome gives I know it's not the generalize xpath `response.xpath('//*[@id="Blog1"]/div[2]/a[9]').extract()` this gave me nothing.

Comment: Page source doesn't contain those pagination buttons (links) - they are generated dynamically

Comment: Anyway To get them sir?

Comment: You can use [Splash](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash) or pyQt5 or requests-html or Selenium ... any tool that supports JavaScript handling. Also you can try [requests with Session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects)

Comment: I have worked with selenium before but that's slow, what would be fastest and most effective library to use with scrapy?

Comment: With Scrapy you can use only Splash. The fastest way will be requests+Session, but it requires some investigations of relationship between HTTP-requests